# Install Ubuntu and run in Windows or through normal boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, multi-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Booting into a Virtual Machine from a physical installation](https://superuser.com/questions/69915/booting-into-a-virtual-machine-from-a-physical-installation)

I like and use Windows 7 more than anything. But there is times when I want to run Ubuntu or some other Linux. However it is aggrivating to have to reboot the computer everytime i want to switch.

My goal is to make it where i can run Ubuntu from a VM or from boot. To explain in more detail:

I want it where when I'm in windows I can run Ubuntu in a VM like VMWare, but if I want to just use Ubuntu I can boot from the same Ubuntu installation when I restart the computer.

So my question is: Can I use VMWare to boot from a REAL partition, then boot Ubuntu from the GRUB menu if I choose to only run Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

I have done a little research after I got the answer from Serge. You can do this with VMs. It is called "Raw Disks".

- VMWare Player does not support this. Only VMWare Workstation.
- Oracle VirtualBox does support this, but it takes some setup.

I have linked some tutorials below.

- VMWare Workstation: [Adding Physical Disks to a Virtual Machine](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_disk_add_raw.html)
- Orcale VirtualBox: [Access Physical Disk in VirtualBox](http://www.sysprobs.com/access-physical-disk-virtualbox-desktop-virtualization-software)

Answer (score 0):

VMWare Workstation offers this feature as Serge said. This [VMWare guide](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/dualboot_tech_note.pdf) will help you through the steps for using a physical partition for your VM.

Have a happy weekend.