# VirtualBox: Make a virtual machine boot from a second bootable hard disk

Tags: virtualbox, windows-8, virtualization, ubuntu-12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>    [Booting into a Virtual Machine from a physical installation](https://superuser.com/questions/69915/booting-into-a-virtual-machine-from-a-physical-installation)

I have 2 bootable hard-disks. One runs Windows 8 and the other runs Ubuntu 12.10. My primary OS would be Windows 8. Can I use VirtualBox to create a virtual machine, and make it boot from the 2nd hard-disk while I am running Windows from the 1st hard-disk and vice-versa?

While trying to create a Virtual machine, I can't see an option to choose the second hard-disk.

I guess, I could convert the physical partition to a virtual disk first, and use it to create a new virtual machine. But, would the changes made to the Virtual disk, persist, if I boot into Ubuntu outside the Virtual machine?

Comment: Seems to be the VHD should obviously be independent of your actual install.

Comment: I'm not sure, but try to change drive letters using `Run` -> `diskmgmt.msc`

Comment: I could do that. But then, sometimes, I don't want to run any OS on VM. I do my development on Linux and Windows. Sometimes, it's a pain to restart to switch OSes. But, I think, I do know that I am asking for a lot. :)