# Booting a Linux Virtual Machine from a physical installation through Win 10 Hyper-V

Tags: windows-10, boot, virtual-machine, linux-mint, hyper-v-manager

I have dual boot Win10 & LinuxMint on my PC. I want to boot the LinuxMint inside Win10 using Hyper-V. I came across the answer https://superuser.com/a/674714/519592. However my PC has SSD and HDD whereas Windows. Linux boot partition and swap partition are on SSD and Linux home partition is on the HDD. So I cannot offline the SSD as it is running Win10.

Could you give me any suggestions?